# I want to make some custom variablepie chart for some special requirement

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I got stuck somewhere and there I want your help. I want a Pie chart data-label feature into the variable Pie chart. which is like the data should stay in the centre of the chart piece.

I tried so many ways but not fit in the centre like the data label indication line.

Please check the code and design below and help me to fix my issue...

[This's the design reference for the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUBzt.png)
[This's the current output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOgGV.png)

[This's the link for the current output...](https://jsfiddle.net/5fohy7kg/#)

```js
<script>

  Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#2B2E33', '#4D5566', '#8590A6', '#B8C3D9', '#02D42E']
  });
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'variablepie',
        style: {
          fontFamily: "'Montserrat-Regular', 'sans-serif'",
          letterSpacing: '0.5px',
        },
        events: {
          load: function() {
            var series = this.series[0],
              distance = series.points[0].shapeArgs.r / 2;
            series.update({
              dataLabels: {
                distance: -distance
              }
            });
          }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: ' '
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> <b> {point.name}</b> {point.y}<br/>'
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        }
    },
    legend: {
      symbolRadius: 0,
      itemStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color:'#8590A6',
          textOverflow: 'clip'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      variablepie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        //showInLegend: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            alignTo: 'center',
            format: '{point.percentage:.1f} %',
            distance: -10,
            style:{
              textOutline: 'none',
              fontSize: 15,
              lineHeight: 0,
              color:'white',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
            filter: {
                property: 'percentage',
                operator: '>',
                value: 2
            }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
        innerSize: '40%',
        zMin: 0,
        name: 'countries',
        data: [{
            name: 'Google',
            y: 25,
            z: 100,
        }, {
            name: 'Facebook',
            y: 14,
            z: 115
        }, {
            name: 'Pinterest',
            y: 11,
            z: 85
        }, {
            name: 'Yelp',
            y: 10,
            z: 90
        }, {
            name: 'Local Services',
            y: 40,
            z: 140
        }]
    }]
  }, function (chart) {
  $legend = $('#customLegend');
  $.each(chart.series[0].data, function (j, data) {
      $legend.append('<div class="item"><div class="symbol" style="background-color:'+data.color+'"></div><div class="serieName" id="">' + data.name + '</div><div class="value" id="">' + data.y + '</div></div>');
  });
  $('#customLegend .item').click(function(){
      var inx = $(this).index(),
          point = chart.series[0].data[inx];
      if(point.visible)
          point.setVisible(false);
      else
          point.setVisible(true);
  });        
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some extra info to your serie in order to position you label correctly.
For instance:

```html
{
            name: 'Pinterest',
            y: 11,
            z: 85,
            dataLabels: {
            distance: -30,
            x: -20
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Yelp',
            y: 10,
            z: 90,
            dataLabels: {
            distance: -30,
            x: 30
            }
```

This may help for static charts.

Comment: Yes, this's working but do you have the suggestions for the dynamic data?

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a demo where the center of the arc point is calculated and used as translate function coordinates to center the data label.

```
 events: {
   render: function() {
     const series = this.series[0];
     series.points.forEach(p => {
       const dataLabel = p.dataLabel;
       const args = p.shapeArgs;
       const angle = (args.start + args.end) / 2;
       const r = (args.innerR + args.r) / 2;
       const x = args.x + (r * Math.cos(angle)) - dataLabel.bBox.width / 2;
       const y = args.y + (r * Math.sin(angle)) - dataLabel.bBox.height / 2;

       dataLabel.translate(x, y)
     })
   }
 }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c3wf85g7/

Comment: Your suggestion is working but the data label isn't in the centre.
Demo Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Deepesh3318/gea3Lz4n/

Comment: @DeepeshYogi try this https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c3wf85g7/ - I added plotTop value to the y coordinate.